# How to Activate the Google Maps Android API v2 its not listed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am getting below errors :

```
    09-13 15:13:56.147: E/b(356): Authentication failed on the server.
    09-13 15:13:56.147: E/Google Maps Android API(356): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
    09-13 15:13:56.157: E/Google Maps Android API(356): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    09-13 15:13:56.157: E/Google Maps Android API(356): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    09-13 15:13:56.157: E/Google Maps Android API(356):
```

Its not listed in the console what to do now how can I get map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have created a project in the console, it's listed right there:

[image]

Then you'll have to go through the Credentials section to create an API key.

Comment: Have you set up the credentials using the same packageName?

Comment: So, probably too late but I just had the exact same thing happen to me and I solved by updating Google Play Services in the SDK Manager and setting up the most recent version in the gradle.

Answer (score 2):

i have solved the issue :

1. Update your google play services to the newest and rebuild the project
2. there are 2 different API KEY should be applied, one for debug and one is for release, it is easier if you create the project using Map template, so you will get goole_map_API.xml on your project. if you use blank / empty project just create the google_map_API.xml on src\debug\res\values folder and src\release\res\values\ folder
3. To create the debug API KEY on the google_maps_apis.xml you will get the link, copy that link and open in the browser, create the credential key using that link. example of the link you will get from the debug file:

```
To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=70:52:69:E7:6F:B9:61:62:C4:8B:F2:1D:A2:28:FE:55:43:4F:FF:08%3Bcom.devdov.myapplication
```

4. After you get the debug key, enter the API KEY to your src\debug\res\values\google_map_APIS.xml.
5. Last thing is create your own API KEY for the release version put the API KEY to the src\release\res\values\google_map_APIS.xml.
6. rebuild your project

this steps is work for me, after more than one day searching and trying